# PHP arrays using keynames and 2 loops

Tags: php, arrays

I know this question is very basic to you all, and I'm truly sorry for asking, but I'm studying arrays right now and I've been asked to do the following learning from textbook, which I hate.

I need to loop through the first level and get the FIELD_NAME and FIELD_LABEL.
Then to loop through again and get all CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS > OPTION_VALUE for each first level array.

My problem is that it fails at the first loop. And I can't get my head around second loops.

Can you provide some guidance please? I need some help on this :(

```
$getAllCustomFields = $api->getAllCustomFields();
foreach ($getAllCustomFields as $item) {
    echo addslashes($item->FIELD_NAME) . ": '" . addslashes($item->FIELD_LABEL) . "',";
}
```

In the array I need to be able to loop and get

```
array(46) {
  ["Secondary_Volunteering__c"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["FIELD_NAME"]=>
    string(25) "Secondary_Volunteering__c"
    ["FIELD_ORDER"]=>
    int(2)
    ["FIELD_FOR"]=>
    string(7) "CONTACT"
    ["FIELD_LABEL"]=>
    string(22) "Secondary Volunteering"
    ["FIELD_TYPE"]=>
    string(11) "MULTISELECT"
    ["FIELD_HELP_TEXT"]=>
    NULL
    ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
    NULL
    ["EDITABLE"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["VISIBLE"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"]=>
    array(9) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["OPTION_ID"]=>
        int(3)
        ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
        string(6) "Events"
        ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["OPTION_ID"]=>
        int(14)
        ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
        string(28) "Flagship Programme"
        ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
    ["DEPENDENCY"]=>
    NULL
    ["JOIN_OBJECT"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["Primary_Volunteering__c"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["FIELD_NAME"]=>
    string(23) "Primary_Volunteering__c"
    ["FIELD_ORDER"]=>
    int(3)
    ["FIELD_FOR"]=>
    string(7) "CONTACT"
    ["FIELD_LABEL"]=>
    string(20) "Primary Volunteering"
    ["FIELD_TYPE"]=>
    string(11) "MULTISELECT"
    ["FIELD_HELP_TEXT"]=>
    NULL
    ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
    NULL
    ["EDITABLE"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["VISIBLE"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"]=>
    array(27) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["OPTION_ID"]=>
        int(87)
        ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
        string(9) "Animal Me"
        ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["OPTION_ID"]=>
        int(51)
        ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
        string(18) "Animals inc Plants"
        ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["OPTION_ID"]=>
        int(13)
        ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
        string(3) "Art"
        ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        ["OPTION_ID"]=>
        int(21)
        ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
        string(12) "Bright Stars"
        ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
    ["DEPENDENCY"]=>
    NULL
    ["JOIN_OBJECT"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: `->` is for object properties. Arrays use `[]`: `$item['FIELD_NAME']`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. That now works. Can you guide me how to only show values from a list. For example ["Secondary_Volunteering__c"] and ["Secondary_Volunteering__a"] for example. And ignore the others.

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach($getAllCustomFields as $fields){
    foreach($fields as $field){
        echo( '<strong>'.$field["FIELD_LABEL"].'</strong><br>');
        foreach ($field["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"] as $cfield){
        echo($cfield["OPTION_VALUE"].'<br>');

        }
         echo('<br>');
    }
   
}
```